# Bucle condicionado de un rango

Tags: python

No logro sacar la primera fecha en la que future_pirces('High') es mayor a prices_df.  En este caso cuando 2100 > 1082 quiero guardar en df3 '2022-05-05'.  Sin embargo, cuando 2000 > 1074 ya no quiero guardar la fecha, una vez tengo una no necesito revisar más.

```
prices_df = [1106, 1098, 1090.625, 1082.577, 1074.52]
future_dates = {'Date': ['2022-05-02', '2022-05-03', '2022-05-04', '2022-05-05', '2022-05-06'],
                'High': [1020, 1005, 966, 2100, 2000],
                }
future_prices = pd.DataFrame(future_dates)
future_prices = future_prices.set_index('Date')


df3.loc[i, 'Break_date'] = future_dates['Date'] if future dates > prices_df
```

En la última de las líneas es donde claramente tengo problemas :/

Gracias!

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el recorrido de bienvenida y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partiendo de tu dataframe en `future_prices`, y haciendo uso de un par de trucos sobre el comportamiento de pandas que después explicaré, puedes hallar la respuesta en una sola expresión:

```
>>> (future_prices.High > prices_df).idxmax()
'2022-05-05'
```

### ¿Cómo funciona?

Primero, `future_prices.High` devuelve una serie con los valores de la columna "High", y gracias a las operaciones vectoriales pandas, puedes comparar directamente esa serie con una lista. Lo que hará pandas será la comparación elemento a elemento, devolviendo `True` en aquellos que lo cumplan y `False` en los que no. Mira:

```
>>> future_prices.High > prices_df
Date
2022-05-02    False
2022-05-03    False
2022-05-04    False
2022-05-05     True
2022-05-06     True
Name: High, dtype: bool
```

Seguidamente hago uso de otro truco. Al resultado de la operación anterior le aplico el método `.idxmax()`. Eso me devuelve el índice del máximo en una serie. En este caso la serie se compone solo de booleanos, pero ocurre que `True` es mayor que `False` debido a la forma en que se comparan booleanos (porque True se representa internamente como 1 y False como 0). Así que el máximo de una columna de booleanos va a ser `True`, y la función `.idxmax()` me devuelve la posición en que aparece ese valor máximo, o en caso de que haya repetidos, del primero de ellos.

Dicho de otra forma, y gracias a que `True>False`, obtengo rápidamente el índice del primer `True` en esa columna. Y ese es justamente el índice de la primera fila en la que se cumpla que High es mayor que el valor correspondiente en `prices_df`.

Comment: La respuesta es muy buena y me funciona perfecto.  Solo que cuando todos son false necesitaria simplemente guardar un null en esa fila y no eliminarla del todo.  ¿Cómo lo podrías hacer?

Comment: Solucionado:    df3.loc[i, 'Break_date'] = (future_prices.High > prices_df).idxmax() if any(future_prices.High > prices_df) else 0

Comment: @Artrade Buena solución, sólo que estás computando dos veces la comparación con `prices_df`. Para evitarlo puedes hacer `aux = future_prices.High > prices_df` y después `df3.loc[i, "Break_date"]= aux.idxmax() if aux.any() else 0`. Observa también que he puesto `aux.any()`en vez de `any(aux)` pues lo primero es una operación pandas mientras que lo segundo es una operación python, y supongo que será más rápida la de pandas.

Comment: Gracias, voy a añadirlo!!  @abulafia quería preguntarte cómo podría hacer para no solo guardar la fecha si no también el high.  Ambos están en la tabla future_Dates pero no veo como hacerlo llegar a la final de df3 donde solo me llega la fecha.  gracias!!

Comment: Una vez tienes el index obtenido de `indice = aux.idxmax()` puedes usarlo para acceder a esa fila `future_prices[indice]`, obteniendo así la fila completa, lo que incluye el valor de High. No obstante no entiendo bien cómo quieres hacerlo llegar a `df3`, imagino que en dos columnas separadas. Y qué valor de High pondrías para el caso en que no has encontrado fecha?

Comment: Hola!  Luego pruebo lo del indice y te digo, gracias!! Quiero ponerlo en una columna separada:  df3.loc[i, "Break_Price"]  y en caso de no tener fecha me gustaría tomar el último de los precios o bien poner un null, ambas soluciones me sirven.  Gracias

Answer (score 1):

### ¡Buen dia!

Primero que nada veo un poco innecesario la linea de codigo:

```
future_prices = future_prices.set_index('Date')
```

De ser posible me gustaria saber que intenciones tiene al poner su llave *"Date"* como su indice. Por otro lado ayudando a resolver su problema de una manera optima tenemos lo siguiente:

### Replicaré su dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

prices_df = [1106, 1098, 1090.625, 1082.577, 1074.52]
future_dates = {'Date': ['2022-05-02', '2022-05-03', '2022-05-04', '2022-05-05', '2022-05-06'],
                'High': [1020, 1005, 966, 2100, 2000],
                }
future_prices = pd.DataFrame(future_dates)
print(future_prices)
```

---

```
         Date  High
0  2022-05-02  1020
1  2022-05-03  1005
2  2022-05-04   966
3  2022-05-05  2100
4  2022-05-06  2000
```

### Solución

Su problema se puede resolver en una linea de codigo de la siguiente manera:

```
fecha_one = future_prices[future_prices["High"] > prices_df].iloc[0,0]
print(fecha_one)
```

Como resultado obtenemos:

```
2022-05-05
```

Este resultado sería la primera fecha donde la columna *"High"* es mayor a *prices_df*

### Indice

Si desea saber el indice de la *coincidencia* seria de la siguiente manera:

```
indice=future_prices[future_prices["Date"]==fecha_one].index.tolist()
print(indice)
[3]
```